# Template specialization from a template class

Tags: c++, templates

There is a template class `A` used in class hierarchy of `B::C_#` which specialize method `create()` of `A`:

```
template <typename T>
class A
  : public std::map<std::string, double (T::*)() const>
{
  ...

  void create();

  ...
};

template <typename T>
void A<T>::create()
{ assert(false); }
```

One of these subclasses `C_#` (let's say `C_0`) was great until recently. Everything went fine until `C_0` decided to become a template. He got everything going except this `create()` specialization. It tries to specialize `create()` the following way:

```
template<class N1, class N2>
class C_0: public B<N1, N2>
{
  ...
}

...

template<class N1, class N2>
some_namespace::A< some_namespace::C_0<N1, N2> >
  some_namespace::C_0<N1, N2>::A_;

template <>
void some_namespace::A< C_0<N1, N2> >::create() // line 1151
{
  blah_(&C_0<N1, N2>::get_stuff);
}
```

but `C_0`'s attempts so far failed:

```
C_0.h:1151:45: error: 'N1' was not declared in this scope
C_0.h:1151:49: error: 'N2' was not declared in this scope
C_0.h:1151:51: error: template argument 1 is invalid
C_0.h:1151:51: error: template argument 2 is invalid
C_0.h:1151:53: error: template argument 1 is invalid
C_0.h:1151:63: error: 'create' is not a template function
```

Please help poor creature to overcome his trouble.

Also tried to do template method specialization in specialized `C_0`:

```
namespace some_namespace
{
  class C_0_specialized: public C_0<double_t, size_t>
  {};

  template <>
  void A<C_0_specialized>::create()
  {
    blah_(&C_0_specialized::get_stuff);
  }
}
```

This time it compiles, but calls the original method, which is `void A<T>::create() { assert(false); }`

**Solution**

Ok, so I ended up doing partial specialization of the whole template class `A` within `C_0` template level with `C_0` argument list:

```
template<class N1, class N2>
class A< C_0<N1, N2> >
{

  ...

  void create()
  {
    blah_(&C_0<N1, N2>::get_stuff);
  }

  ...

}
```

The reason is because: 1) partial specialization of template methods is not allowed, so it is not possible to specialize just `void create()` and when class is partially specialized all methods and variables have to be re-defined in the specialization; 2) explicit specialization of template method `void create()` is not possible within `C_0` level because `A` depends on `C_0` template argument list; 3) Moving `void create()` specialization to `C_0_specialized`, where it could be explicitly specialized because at `C_0_specialized` the template argument list is resolved, was not possible because the instance of `A` (instantiated as `A_` in the code above) is used within template `C_0` and therefore `A_` would not see the specialization of `A` at `C_0` level. That's why at that level it was calling the base version of `void create()`. Also moving `A_` to the level of `C_0_specialized` was not possible due to too much overhead.

Good thing is the class `A` is not big, but still it would be preferable to specialize only `void create()`.

I found [this resource](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fpartial_specialization.htm) very useful for explaining differences between explicit and partial specialization of templates.

Comment: Well the compiler is right. You need to pass actual types rather than `N1` and `N2`. It's your choice.

Comment: @stefan is there a way to get the right syntax for that within the template C_0 rather moving it up to the concrete instances of C_0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you forgot to tell the compiler that `N1` and `N2` are types

```
template<class N1, class N2>
void some_namespace::A< C_0<N1, N2> >::create() // line 1151
{
  blah_(&C_0<N1, N2>::get_stuff);
}
```

This still doesn't work, because there is no class `A<C_0<N1,N2>>` defined. First declare that.
*Note*: you did define `A<T>`, but that's the general case, not the specialisation you're not trying to define a member for.

Btw, the following three lines make absolutely no sense whatsover.

```
template<class N1, class N2>
some_namespace::A< some_namespace::C_0<N1, N2> >
  some_namespace::C_0<N1, N2>::A_;
```

Comment: @stefan why? Is this a guideline? (if so, where can I find it?) btw, beste Gruesse nach HD.

Comment: yeah i tried that, but was getting `invalid use of incomplete type 'class some_namespace::A<some_namespace::C_0<N1, N2> >'`

Comment: @Walter: It doesn't explain _why_ it solves the problem. (Gruß zurück, wohin auch immer ;-) )

Comment: @Stefan Ich hab ein paar schoene Jahr dort verbracht. Gerade in Paris, aber normalerweise in England.

Comment: @Walter: `C_0` is declared as a template: `class C_0: public B<N1, N2>`. The specialization of `some_namespace::A< C_0<N1, N2> >::create()` takes place in the same file where `C_0` is declared, after the declaration. I tried your approach, but I got `invalid use of incomplete type 'class some_namespace::A<some_namespace::C_0<N1, N2> >'`. Yes those lines are not related to the problem, but they make sense for other stuff. I'll take them out.

Comment: @Dimon You never defined the specialised class template `A<C_0<N1,N2>>`. You must define that before you define its members.

Comment: @Walter the class `A` is defined as a template above and I'm trying to specialize just a single method from that class. Do you mean I have to specialize the whole template class? I tried this but it doesn't work:

Comment: `template<class N1, class N2>
  class some_namespace::A< C_0<N1, N2> >...`

Comment: error: extra qualification not allowed, error: template class without a name

Comment: you must not define `some_namespace::A<...>`, but put the definition `template<...> class A<...>` into the namespace. It worked (compiled) for me at least.

Comment: Thank you :). In this case I would have to re-define all members of `A`, right? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Also tried to do `create()` method specialization in specialized `C_0` (see edited above), but it still calls the `create()` in the base template `A`

Comment: @Dimon no not right. Only the class definition must be in the namespace. For the definition of member methods you can use the resolution.

Comment: @Walter. I ended up doing partial specialization of the whole class. See the solution above. Let me know if you know a way to do only specialization of `create()`. One thing is I can't touch base `A`. Thank you very much for your help.